# Changing RichBoxText font using ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

So, I had this code which doesn't seem to be working, I'm trying to change RichBoxText using ComboBox, only **SelectedItems** seem to be working (From **form1_load**). I'm a beginner in programming, so please go easy on me.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace FormatarTexto
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                comboBoxTipo.Items.Add("Arial");
                comboBoxTipo.Items.Add("Times New Roman");
                comboBoxTipo.Items.Add("Verdana");


                comboBoxEstilo.Items.Add("Normal");
                comboBoxEstilo.Items.Add("Negrito");
                comboBoxEstilo.Items.Add("Itálico");
                comboBoxEstilo.Items.Add("Sublinhado");

                comboBoxTamanho.Items.Add("10");
                comboBoxTamanho.Items.Add("12");
                comboBoxTamanho.Items.Add("14")


                comboBoxTipo.SelectedItem = "Arial";
                comboBoxTamanho.SelectedItem = "12";
                comboBoxEstilo.SelectedItem = "Normal";

            }

            private void Formatar()
            {
                int tamanho = int.Parse(comboBoxTamanho.Text);
                FontStyle estilo = new FontStyle();
                switch(comboBoxEstilo.SelectedItem.ToString())
                {
                    case "Normal":
                        estilo = FontStyle.Regular;
                        break;

                    case "Negrito":
                        estilo = FontStyle.Bold;
                        break;

                    case "Itálico":
                        estilo = FontStyle.Italic;
                        break;

                    case "Sublinhado":
                        estilo = FontStyle.Underline;
                        break;
                }

              richTextBoxTexto.SelectionFont = new Font(comboBoxTipo.SelectedItem.ToString(), tamanho, estilo);
            }
        }
    }
```

Richbox's text isn't changing when I change the value from ComboBox. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is any text selected in the RichTextBox?

Comment: It selects but disappears when I click on a ComboBox

Comment: That's because the focus is changing to the combobox, so the selection highlight is no longer visible in the RichTextBox. If you tab back into the RichTextBox, you'll see the selection again. Try Koen Meijer's solution. You need to create an event handler that is called whne the combobox selection changes. Double clicking on the combobox in the form designers should create it. Then call `Formatar()` from the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an eventhandler on the comboBoxEstilo. In this way you can catch the event that when you change the value in the Combobox.

To add the eventhandler add it for instance in the form load :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   this.comboBoxEstilo.SelectedIndexChanged += 
        new System.EventHandler(comboBoxEstilo_SelectedIndexChanged);
   ...
}
```

And add the Eventhandler :

```
    private void comboBoxEstilo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Formatar();
    }
```

Comment: But Fontfamily and size don't seem to be working too.. And sorry, I'm still not into eventhandler right now.

Comment: @dotke Naturally those aren't working either. You're doing nothing, so nothing happens. Koen, he needs it explained how to to create an event handler.

Comment: Added explaination how to add the eventhandler to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. When you call formatar from the eventhandler, it will work.

Comment: Welp, I deeply apologise for the trouble. It worked, I used eventhandler, it was pointed out in instructions that I was reading... Jeez.